# Hibernate: Adding extra columns to the join table between two entities having a Many to One relationship

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am creating an application where I need to map the following relation:

```
User-------->UserSubscription----------->Subscription
```

I don't have any problem in mapping the above relation, but I need to add some extra columns in the `UserSubscription` table because a user can renew a subscription in which case User_Id and Subscription_Id will be same resulting in primary key violation, thus I think that 'UserSubscription' table should has its own primary key. Also I want to add attributes like `Subscription_start_date` and `Subscription_end_date` to 'UserSubscription'. So what should I do? Should I create a new entity or there is some other way?

Comment: you want to add User_ID and Subscription_Id in UserSubscription

Comment: My personal suggestion would be: create explicit pairing object. [Here](https://trovepromo-tf.trove-stg.com/0m1-sd/stackoverflow.com/a/16827671) is some kind of how to. Explicit pairing entity will later simplify your life when searching for User or Subscription based on the other (easy with pairing object). And also, pairing object could have many other mapped properties..

Comment: @GautamSavaliya , No I want to add Subscription_start_date and Subscription_end_date to the UserSubscription. User_Id and Subscription_Id is already there in the UserSubscription.